# QTooltip display position

Tags: qt, tooltip, mouseevent

I've added a `QTooltip` on a `mouseMoveEvent` for my widget. This tooltip is being displayed way above my mouse cursor.

```
void myWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

  QToolTip::showText(event->scenePos().toPoint(),
                       QString::number(event->scenePos().x()) + ", "
                       + QString::number(event->scenePos().y()));

  QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

How do I customize the tooltip's position w.r.t my cursor? I want to display this tooltip just below my cursor.

Comment: What if you try event->globalPos() in showText? Is it working as you want?

Comment: @Chernobyl `globalPos()` is not even an option here, I can use `event->pos()` , `event->scenePos()` or `event->screenPos()`. I guess `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` only allows these three.

Comment: Yes, try screenPos it should be same as globalPos in mouseEvent. Is it work properly?

Comment: Yeah, it worked. Thanks.. but is there any other way you could override the default position it sets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `screenPos` instead of `scenePos`. For example:

```
void myWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event)
{

  QToolTip::showText(event->screenPos().toPoint(),
                       QString::number(event->scenePos().x()) + ", "
                       + QString::number(event->scenePos().y()));

  QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent(event);
}
```

Another approach is to use magic numbers such as minus 2  or minus 3 but I think that `screenPos` or `globalPos`(in simple `mouseEvent`) is better.